# I can not start HTTP server Admin on AS400

Tags: ibm-midrange, http-server

The error message is...

```
 CPF9898 Escape 40 19/03/16 11:11:55.552230 QLWISVRA QSYS *STMT QLWIIHSMOD QHTTPSVR *STMT 

 From module . . . . . . . . : QLWIMSG 5761SS1 V6R1M0 080215 Job Log MLCNAS05 19/03/16 11:11:55 Page 2 

 Job name . . . . . . . . . . : ADMIN 

 User . . . . . . : QTMHHTTP 

 Number . . . . . . . . . . . : 022548 

 Job description . . . . . . : QZHBHTTP 

 Library . . . . . : QHTTPSVR 

 MSGID TYPE SEV DATE TIME FROM PGM LIBRARY INST TO PGM LIBRARY INST

 From procedure . . . . . . : sendStartStopMessage__10LwiMessageFPcsN31 

 Statement . . . . . . . . . : 55 

 To module . . . . . . . . . : MOD_IBMLWI

 To procedure . . . . . . . : startLwiServer__FP10apr_pool_tP10lwi_conf_t 

 Statement . . . . . . . . . : 105 

 Message . . . . : INTEGRATED WEB APPLICATION SERVER Admin1 FAILED TO START. SERVER Admin1 NOT FOUND IN REGISTRY. 

 Cause . . . . . : This message is used by application programs as a general escape message.
```

Where the Admin1 configure? 
 How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Any messages prior to that in the joblog?

You may want to look in the Apache log(s):
/QIBM/UserData/HTTPA/admin/logs/HTTPAdmin.log
/QIBM/UserData/HTTPA/admin/logs/error_log

More troubleshooting steps [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzaie/rzaietroublewebadmin.htm)

Comment: hello， there is no any prior log. And also no logs in /QIBM/UserData/HTTPA/admin/logs/HTTPAdmin.log and /QIBM/UserData/HTTPA/admin/logs/error_log